# Postgres duplicate phone numbers where name is different

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, count, window-functions

Using a simple table consisting of firstname, lastname, and phone (all text fields), how can I find how many unique phone numbers are used by more than one person?

I know how to find how many duplicate phone numbers there are, but I only want a count of how many when the phone number is a duplicate where the firstname + lastname + phone is different.

I suspect it would be something similar to the following that shows how many complete duplicates there are:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, phone
FROM people
GROUP BY lastname, firstname, phone
HAVING count(*) >1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select 1
    from mytable
    group by phone
    having count(*) > 1
) t
```

This assumes that the same phone number is not affected twice to the same person.

Another option is window functions (which also properly handle the above case):

```
select count(*) filter(where rn = 2)
from (
    select dense_rank() over(partition by phone order by firstname, lastname) rn
    from mytable
) t
```

Comment: This gives me a count of all the duplcates, but I only want duplicates when the phone number is duplicated but when firstname + lastname + phone is different.

Comment: @Ryan: I think I mentionned that in my answer. You should try the second query.

Comment: I think you are right. Thanks! The results look about what I was expecting, but I will need to expand somehow to verify. How can I print out the phone numbers in that count?

Comment: @Ryan: Something like: `select phone, count(*) cnt from (select phone, dense_rank() over(partition by phone order by firstname, lastname) rn from mytable) t group by phone having max(rn) > 1`

Comment: You are an SQL virtuoso! Thanks. The count column counts all the duplicate numbers, not just the ones with different names, but the list of phone numbers solved the my case. Thanks again!